# No module named 'xdg.BaseDirectory'

Tags: bash

After the installation of syncal `pip3 install 'syncall[caldav, tw]'`
khal no longer works:
**Error message:**

```
yoga-x1:~$ **khal**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/khal", line 2, in <module>
    from khal.cli import main_khal
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/khal/cli.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .settings import InvalidSettingsError, get_config
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/khal/settings/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .settings import get_config  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/khal/settings/settings.py", line 26, in <module>
    import xdg.BaseDirectory
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xdg.BaseDirectory'
```

**Current python version:**
Python 3.10.12

**khal needs:**
Python 3.8+

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add your `import` statements?

Comment: @ eyoung100 hello,
What do you mean exactly? I don't import anything, with the command `khal` or `khal calendar` I can call up the calendar.

Comment: Try `pip install pyxdg`.  See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871838/xdg-basedirectory-import-error)

Comment: @eyoung100 hello, Result:
User installation by default, as normal site packages are not writable
Requirement already fulfilled: pyxdg in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.27)